# What does "syndicated copies" mean?

Tags: word-usage, sentence-meaning, verbs

In November 2014, The Washington Post inadvertently published a photograph of all seven of the TSA master keys in an article[151] about TSA baggage handling. The photograph was later removed from the original article, but it still appears in some **syndicated copies**.

6. (Journalism & Publishing) (tr) to sell (articles, photographs, etc) to several newspapers for simultaneous publication(source:Collins English Dictionary)

My question is:

If the copies published in The Washington Post were removed does the phrase "syndicated copies" mean other copies of photos that were sold **to other newspapers than** The Washington Post by a syndicate (A news agency selling to different newspapers)? Or perhaps the word "copies" doesn't mean those of photographs but of articles which were sindicated.

Comment: The syndicated 'copies' are of the article that the photograph appeared in.

Answer (score 2):

In this case I would take it to mean that the photos were removed from the article as it appears at the Washington Post site (and probably any feed they continue to publish). However, other papers received the article as originally printed including the pictures and still make the photos available. "Syndicated copies" refers to those copies of the original article.